# Why isn't this loop vectorized?

Tags: c++, optimization, simd, vectorization

One particular hot spot when I profile a code I am working on, is the following loop:

```
for(int loc = start; loc<end; ++loc)
    y[loc]+=a[offset+loc]*x[loc+d];
```

where the arrays y, a, and x have no overlap.  It seems to me that a loop like this should be easily vectorized, however when I compile using g++ with the options "-O3 -ftree-vectorize -ftree-vectorizer-verbose=1", I get no indication that this particular loop was vectorized.  However, a loop occurring just before the code above:

```
for(int i=0; i<m; ++i)
    y[i]=0;
```

does get vectorized according to the output.  Any thoughts on why the first loop is not vectorized, or how I might be able to fix this?  (I am not all that educated on the concept of vectorization, so I am likely missing something quite obvious)

As per Oli's suggestion, turning up the verbosity yields the following notes (while I am usually good at reading compiler warnings/errors/output, I have no idea what this means):

```
./include/mv_ops.h:89: note: dependence distance  = 0.
./include/mv_ops.h:89: note: accesses have the same alignment.
./include/mv_ops.h:89: note: dependence distance modulo vf == 0 between *D.50620_89 and *D.50620_89
./include/mv_ops.h:89: note: not vectorized: can't determine dependence between *D.50623_98 and *D.50620_89
```

Comment: Why don't you work with pointers to `a[offset]` and `x[d]` instead?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion K-ballo.  Just did what you suggested, which makes things a bit more readable (though it has no effect on my vectorizing).

Comment: @K-ballo: I doubt it makes a difference.

Comment: Are those `x`, `y`, and `a` declared in that function as arrays or pointers?

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: Its just a matter of personal preference. That's why it was a comment and not an answer.

Comment: @MSN- x, y, and a are pointers that are passed to the function (x, and a are const*)

Comment: Maybe try manually lifting the subexpressions `a+offset` aned `x+d` out of the loop?  As in `const int *p1 = a+offset;` `const int *p2 = x+d;` `for(...) y[loc] += p1[loc] * p2[loc];` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to tell the compiler that `x`, `y`, and `a` do not overlap. In C/C++ terms that means telling the compiler that those pointers do not alias by declaring them with [`restrict` (or `__restrict`)](http://cellperformance.beyond3d.com/articles/2006/05/demystifying-the-restrict-keyword.html). gcc is very aggressive about optimizations when it assumes no aliasing, so be careful.

Comment: Thanks MSN- that did the trick.  Now time to read that link and understand what I did.

Answer (score 4):

One possibility is that the compiler can't guarantee that there are no aliases.  In other words, how can the compiler be sure that `y`, `a` and `x` don't overlap in some way?

If you turn the verbosity level up, you may get some extra info.

Comment: Hi Oli-  Is there any way to tell the compiler that there is no overlap?   Also, I added some more verbose output from the compiler- I suspect it is helpful, (and seems to indicate what you suspect?) but I am not quite sure what it means.

Comment: @MarkD: You could try to use `restrict` or `__restrict` on the pointers.